# PHP - Remotely Fetch Data From Google/flights

Tags: php, google-api

Can anyone point me right direction for fetching data from google/flights page? I'm programming PHP, I tried CURL, but that doesn't work at all... I looked at all google api titles and it seems no API is related to that page

Comment: [This link might help you](http://www.nohup.in/blog/using-json-google-flights) :)

Comment: looks like the author has deconstructed queries in the article, but nothing that leads me to my goal :| but thanks for sharing